# Call a Javascript function from a JSP Servlet forward

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

What I'm trying to do today is to directly call a Javascript function from a JSP Servlet response. What does that mean? Here's the code:

**Servlet, This is contained in myServlet.java**

```
// Takes an XML already previously parsed as a string as input
CharSequence confirm= "something";
    if (xml.contains(confirm)) {
            // Carry on
            // If it is contained we needn't go further
    } else {
        // "couldn't find confirms content
        errorMessage = "Does not contain confirm";
        // "If ^ quit this servlet"
        request.setAttribute("rol", this.rol);
        request.setAttribute("user", this.user);
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        forwardToJSP(request, response, "/myJSP.jsp");
    }
```

Now In Javascript I already have defined a function I want to be called. It is something along these lines:

**Javascript, This is contained in myJSP.jsp**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    // Assume all document.getElementById calls are properly implemented,
    //   they call real variables that exist elsewhere, but not shown 
    //   here due to irrelevance.
    window.errorExists = function() {
        var errorExists = document.getElementById("terror");
        errorExists.setAtribute("terror", "Does not contain confirm");
        if (errorExists.attributes == "Does not contain confirm"){
           if(confirm("Cannot find content, do you wish to add it?")){
               anotherFunctionCall();
           } else {
               // Don't do anything
           }
    }
}
</script>
```

Now, in simple terms what I want to do is to call my Javascript function from the aforementioned JSP. I think cannot do so with work arounds such as:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' name='Button' value='Search' onclick=\"searchRecord('"+ argument + "');\"></td></tr>");
```

Because the other function wouldn't be called, also there's an update to Javascript variables.

How would one go around this?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this javascript method defined or can be reached from myJSP.jsp file?

Comment: If you forward to JSP you can place JSP attribute directly to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call that method in `onload` parameter of body of JSP page.

As you are already calling a JSP page using Forward method, your JSP page is getting loaded when you call it. You can call your method in body tag of JSP page as follows:

```
<body onload="YourMehodName()">
```

alternatively, you can put this script at the bottom of your JSP which will get called on loading of your page.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on your initial response?